# Merging tables with common attributes

Tags: sql, database, oop, field, normalization

I am designing a database that contains JOBSEEKERS who can be matched to VACANCIES. I am looking for an effecient and good way to store the common attributes between the 2 (There's a lot). For example a JOBSEEKER has skills and a VACANCY has required skills; or a JOBSEEKER has a salary requirement and a VACANCY has a salary offer.

Right now I am considering two options:

1. Storing all the attributes or each table in their own table.
2. Creating another table that contains the common attributes. Each row would represent the attributes for either a VACANCY or JOBSEEKER. I would then link each record to either a VACANCY or a JOBSEEKER.

Which way should is the correct way of going about this? Other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JobSeeker` and `Vacancy` are two separate entities.  In most cases, you would store the values in separate tables with separate columns.  Although they have overlapping attributes, they have many attributes that are not common.

The, use application code logic (often implemented in SQL) to match between the two.

For something like skills, you actually want junction tables:  `JobseekerSkills` and `VacancySkills` to list each of the skills.  These would, in turn, reference another table `Skills` to ensure that the skills are common between the two entities.